# Crystal Report Duplicating in details?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report, duplicates

so I have a template in Crystal reports using vb.net, I changed my data source location and that source still contains the needed tables for my report, the problem is this... My original template displays the exact report but when I changed its data source it duplicates the data in the details section(e.g I made a query that will show 1 item only,but instead I get 4).

Here is a screenshot of my problem: 
[image]

(original at http://tinypic.com/r/5by6ih/5)

I want to alter the template rather than to make another one

Answer (score 0):

This is normally down to an issue with the underlying SQL query. If you open the the report in Crystal (or visual studio) you should be able to "Show SQL Query". Run the query in Query Analyser or SQL Server Management Studio and look at the result.

If the underlying reason isn't then immediately apparent please paste the resulting output.

Comment: it seems to be that the sql query changed, how can I edit the sql query in the template?

Comment: The query is normally built dynamically based on the tables and fields used in the report. What is the difference between the before/after that's causing the duplication?

Comment: In its original template(before changing its data source), the query can precisely generate sales reports with exact items(e.g Nine Inch Nails shows only once)..but after changing its data source it duplicates the nine inch nails in the screenshot(thus the query changed too)

Comment: I meant what is the difference in the SQL before/after

Comment: it contains more inner joins after I change the data source(thus causing the duplication), take note that the data source I altered contains the same database(only different in server and database name)

Comment: right- which additional table(s) have now been joined in? which fields from these tables have been used?

Comment: I can't view the exact query anymore because the previous datasource because it is from the laptop of my friend. I don't know why I am having trouble changing it back to my local datasource